# Connect to a local MySQL Router from another computer

Tags: c#, mysql, database, database-design, schema

I am currently about to undergo a programming project that requires me to have access of data on a table in a MySQL schema that is on my desktop. I am trying to connect to this schema from visual studio on my laptop.

What I am trying to do is link the two so I will be able to access the data on the table on the MySQL schema. Is this possible over two computers? And if the link is made, will I be able to work with the database while I am at school? If it would work how would I do it?

I am currently a COMPLETE novice at MySQL, I only started to learn it last night. However I am ok at C# on visual studio.

Comment: MySQL is a complete database server, so of course you can access it on another computer provided that the two computers are able to connect. Whether you can do it from school, is a question of opening your firewall to certain ports. Personally I wouldn't bother with it.

Comment: How would I go about connecting the two?

Comment: @D McCracken: On the client (laptop) you specify which server (desktop) your database resides in. You do this in the connection string. Either specify a wellknown DNS name or the IP-address. On the same network this shouldn't be a problem. How to set it up so you can use it remotely is not for this forum.

Answer (score 0):

It's as easy as connecting it in your laptop.all you need to do is allow port access in the firewall.in you connection string add ip address or computer name.of the host server as your host.
  Something like this.

"Datasource='192.168.1.1';port ='3306'; database='mydb';username='root';password='123'";

Comment: Thanks, where would I find my Datasource? I know my port is 3306 but I don't know where my datasource is? Where would I find that?

Comment: If the database is located in your laptop datasource is that laptop and in your connection string it would be 'localhost'.since now database is not in your laptop, ipaddress of where the database is is the host this the datasource.am assuming you have a network connection to where database is located.if not ayou will need that connection.and that's where you get ipaddress from.